# JAXB unmarshall, same oject - multiple instances

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following data structure

```
public class League {

protected int Id;
protected List<Player> players;
protected List<Game> games;
}

public class Player {
protected string email;
protected League league;
}

public class Game {

protected int Id;
protected Player playerOne;
protected Player playerTwo;
protected int playerOneScore;
protected int playerTwoScore;
protected Round round;
}
```

My problem is that the same Player object should appear in the list of players for the league, but can appear within many games in that league, as wither playerone or playerTwo.

JAXB is unmarshalling as separate objects, and even if I run a foreach loop after unmarshalling to match any players within a game to any players in the league with the same email address they don't become the same object.

How can I make it so the a Game object uses the same player objects in the list and doesn't create its own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding playerId to the player class and then after unmarshalling would match player objects via ids

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I do not really like the design of the entities, but it is an another question. (For example the League is a property of a player and should not be mapped on the other side in my opinion.)

Aniway if you keep this structure you should collect all the different entities and load them by the order of their dependencies. In your case there is a circle in the dependency graph so you should use @xmltransient ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) annotation to exclude some of the both way mapping.
In this solution you should make the following transient

```
protected List<Player> players;
```

and convert

```
protected List<Game> games;
```

use @xmladapter: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/advanced_concepts006.htm Whith the help of this concept you should be able to "convert" your entity into a key (id/email in your case) and resolve it whyle loading.

I really recommend to reconsider cleaning the mapping on your entities. ;)

**Edit:** By cleaning I ment to remove the circular dependencies. A version of cleaner entities in my opinion would look like this:

```
public class League {
   protected int Id;
   //other property?
   //protected String name;
}

public class Player {
   protected string email;
   protected League league;
}

public class Game {
   protected int Id;
   protected Player playerOne;
   protected Player playerTwo;
   protected int playerOneScore;
   protected int playerTwoScore;
   protected Round round;
}
```

In this case your dependencies are [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). In this case yo still have to use the mentioned #Xmladapter. Here is a [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/resolve-jaxb-cycle-errors/index.html) which describes almost the same issue you have. There are a lot of choices, each solving the problem from a diffenren angle, feel free to use any of them.

Comment: By cleaning the mapping do you mean remove the the circular dependencies?

Comment: I enriched the answer with some additional information. Hope it is helpful now, I am not a native speaker so sometimes I am not the best describing solutions.

Comment: Sort of, after stored each player id within the game and then when I import the XML file I get the player with this Id and assign it to the game

Comment: As I see you used the provided solution :) could you please accept the answer?